# SDL - Window data

Tags: c++, sdl

I was browsing SDL documentation and I found `WindowData` ([SDL_SetWindowData](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowData) and [SDL_GetWindowData](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowData)).
What is the use of these functions? It stores `void` pointer associated with name, so is it only for storing my objects, which I can use later? Or does it have importance in `SDL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions are supposed to let you store a pointer pointing to arbitrary data (e.g. a memory buffer of your choice or an object) with a window object:

```
MyObject *object_ptr = new MyObject(); // Your custom object
object_ptr->data = 42; // Your custom data
SDL_SetWindowData(window, "mycustomdata", object_ptr);

// Somewhere else in your code in a place where you have access to 'window'
MyObject *object_ptr = SDL_GetWindowData(window, "mycustomdata");
// do whatever you want with object_ptr..
```

This behavior mimics the `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, pointer);` call of win32 API.

Comment: Good example and really the documentation should have something like this in

Comment: Note [`name` must be non-NULL & non-empty](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.0/src/video/SDL_video.c#L2106-L2110).